# Solve the following set of equations using matrix algebra [A|B] method

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Solve the following set of equations using matrix algebra ( [A|B] method, substitute one variable by parameter t, find general solution with parameter) and show the solution when $t=0$:

\begin{cases}
x_1-x_2=4\\[6px]
x_1+x_2+x_3=3
\end{cases}

Answer (score 0):

HINT: adding the two given equations we obtain $$2x_1=7-x_3$$ set now $x_3=t$ and you have the solution of your System